# Can't understand how to use for...next loops in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I know that this code can be easily rewritten to use a loop, but I can't.

```
k1 = (exk - 3 * increment)
k2 = k1 + 0.01
k3 = k2 + 0.01
k4 = k3 + 0.01
k5 = k4 + 0.01
k6 = k5 + 0.01
k7 = k6 + 0.01
Cells(7, 2).Value = k1

Cells(8, 2).Value = k2

Cells(9, 2).Value = k3

Cells(10, 2).Value = k4

Cells(11, 2).Value = k5

Cells(12, 2).Value = k6

Cells(13, 2).Value = k7
```

Comment: First up on google: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html

Comment: `for <variable> = <start> to <end> {step <increment>}` `for y=7 to 12:cells(y,2)=k1:k1=k1+0.01:next y`

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
Sub Rewrite_Code()
    Dim k() As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Const x = 7
    ReDim k(x)

    k1 = (exk - 3 * increment)
    'Redim Preserve k(i+1) '(this can using when program situation interactively changes)
    For i = 1 To x
        k(i + 1) = k(i) + 0.01
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 6, 2).Value = k(i)
    Next i
End Sub 'Rewrite
```

Comment: Is there a need for the redim each time?  `Dim arr() As Double: Const x = 7: ReDim arr(x):for I=1 to x`

Comment: Nathan_Sav, Right. Thanks. I revised code, according your notice.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, Using `Preserve` approach prepare confidential  situation for beginners and widen guidance. They can improve performance as your advise in future experiences. I suggest this positioning for newcomers to programming.

Comment: @MGae2M You forgot the `to x` tho :)

Comment: Also, not picking fault, an array can be dropped straight into a range.  So `activesheet.cells(7,2).resize(x,1).value=arr` should do the job with one put back to the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you mean?

```
Const FirstRow As Long = 7
Dim K1 As Double
Dim i As Long

K1 = 13                 ' your formula is (exc - 3) * increment
For i = 1 To 7
    Cells(i + FirstRow - 1, 2).Value = K1
    K1 = K1 + 0.01
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ForNext()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Long, arr As Variant, exk As Long, increment As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")      'set the name of your Worksheet

    exk = 5 
    increment = 1

    arr = ws.Range(ws.Cells(7, 2), ws.Cells(13, 2)) 'copy range to array

    arr(1, 1) = (exk - 3) * increment               'set first array item

    For r = 2 To 7
        arr(r, 1) = arr(r - 1, 1) + 0.01            'set the rest of the items
    Next

    ws.Range(ws.Cells(7, 2), ws.Cells(13, 2)) = arr 'copy array back to range
End Sub
```

---

- copy the range to array (B7:B13); the first item in array (B7) starts at index 1 - `arr(1, 1)`
- set the first element in the array to your formula: `arr(1, 1) = (exk - 3) * increment`
- iterate over the rest of the array, increment each element based on the previous value
- place the array back on the range

Answer (score 0):

one dimension array sample

```
Sub test()
    Dim exk, increment
    Dim vResult()
    Dim i As Integer
    exk = 5  'setting your value
    increment = 2 'setting your value

    ReDim vResult(1 To 7) 'array one dimension
    vResult(1) = exk - 3 * increment
    For i = 2 To 7
        vResult(i) = vResult(i - 1) + 0.01
    Next i
    Range("b7").Resize(7) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vResult)

End Sub
```